# Parentheses around parameters in explicit F# constructor definition

Tags: constructor, f#

When presented with the below four classes, my editor, VS2013, accepts the first three but gets confused by the fourth one.

```
type ClassOne =
    val mutable myint: int
    new (j) = { myint= j }
    new () = ClassOne 1

type ClassTwo =
    val mutable myint: int
      new j = { myint= j }
    new () = ClassTwo 2

type ClassThree =
    val mutable myint: int
    new j = { myint= j }
     new () = ClassThree 3

type ClassFour =
    val mutable myint: int
    new j = { myint= j }
    new () = ClassFour 4 // confusion here
```

My question is, in `ClassFour` when I use neither parentheses nor 'crooked' indentation for the constructor, what does the compiler think I am trying to do?

Comment: None of your type definition follow the standard definition for defining a class in F#. You're mixing classes with records, which are two separate things

Comment: That totally looks like a parser bug.

Comment: This is weird. Note that some of the indents in `ClassTwo` and `ClassThree` are off. if you "fix" them, both classes stop compiling as well. If you further indent one of the constructor lines in `ClassFour`, it's going to compile too.

Comment: @KevinAvignon No this is valid syntax for classes and structs, even though less it's a lot common than primary constructors. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors#construction-of-structures